# A phrase or neologism which describes obsolete technology-related neologisms

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, neologisms

Neologisms and slang that are inspired by technology are increasingly commonplace, e.g.:

- 'Why don't you just *google* it?'  or
- '*Text* me.'

Some of these neologisms leave our lexicon as quickly as they enter it, e.g.

- '*Page* me when you get there.'

Is there a phrase or neologism which describes the antiquated nature of another neologism, like the verb 'page' in the above example?

Comment: Two thousand and late.

Comment: [Archaic technological nomenclature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_archaic_technological_nomenclature)

Comment: By the way, pagers are still used and cost hospitals billions. http://money.cnn.com/2013/05/07/technology/enterprise/hospital-pagers/

Comment: A _metaneologism._

Comment: Stale and deprecated terms.

Comment: Somehow an obsolete neologism seems like an oxymoron.

Comment: @JohnLawler - How about "neolithiclogism"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Merriam Webster's word of the day serendipitously brought me the answer I was looking for today so I thought I would update this question.

The word I was looking for is "retronym":

From Merriam Webster

> a term (such as analog watch or snail mail) that is newly created and
>   adopted to distinguish the original or older version, form, or example
>   of something from other, more recent versions, forms, or examples

Comment: I fail to see how that answers your original question.

Comment: Interesting, go on.. @oerkelens

Comment: Is it because retronym only implies datedness indirectly?

Comment: A retronym can be coined _today_ to describe something that already existed and that is still relevant today. You were asking about words that were coined _in the past_ and are no longer relevant.

Comment: Yes, but let's think through a hypothetical example.  If someone started referring to a 'page' from a pager as let's say an 'obsolete tweet' then it would be a retronym and it also would describes the 'antiquated nature of another neologism' i.e. page fulfilling both categories of my question, no?

Answer (score 4):

I might suggest referring to such items as *paleologisms*.  It's listed in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paleologism) (and has been for some years), but not in more traditional dictionaries, suggesting that *paleologism* is also a neologism.

> Paleologism: *A phrase that was coined in the past but is now obsolete*

Answer (score 1):

You could say *[passé](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/passe)*

> out-of-date: *passé ideas*

*Collins*

Or you could say *[that's so last year](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/yytan/Tan_Ying_Ying/Publications_files/JoP_LW_TYY.pdf)!* [or some other ancient period]

Wee and Ying at *ScienceDirect.com*

You could say *[old hat](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/old-hat)*, but *old hat* is probably old hat by now.

Answer (score 0):

The definition,  *[out-of-fashion](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/words-that-have-gone-out-of-fashion) words*,  is used to refer to words who had seen a sudden increase in usage but for only a relatively short period, like the terms 'born and dead'  during the technology development of the recent years.

[Words that have gone out of fashion](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/words-that-have-gone-out-of-fashion) ( from Wordnik).

9 [Old-fashioned](http://mashable.com/2014/03/04/old-tech-terms/) Tech Terms You Still Use Today:

> - Old terminology dies hard. Though technology changes swiftly from day to day, there are still old-fashioned terms we cling to, using them frequently even though they no longer have a relevant meaning. We "tune in" to the "tube," all with the aid of the trusty "clicker."